# How do I stop Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from consistently hanging on shutdown and restart?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, shutdown, restart, usb-installation

I wanted to try Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my old laptop and managed to get it installed with USB boot. Ubuntu boots properly and at first glance it seemed to work fine, but when I restart or shut down via the menu it just hangs and I have to use the physical power button to turn it off. On the restart it shows a black screen and nothing happens, and on the shutdown it shows a black screen with the Ubuntu logo at the bottom.

The laptop is an ACER aspire 5560G (750 GB harddisk and 8 GB RAM) and came with Windows 7 installation. Initially I wanted to get it as dual boot so I installed Ubuntu using the "Something else" option and creating the / and /home partitions like I saw in a guide, using free space not used by a Windows partition. Apparently I lost my Windows boot after that so with nothing to lose I reinstalled Ubuntu with the "erase disk and install" option.

Could it be that this Ubuntu OS is too modern for my hardware and that creates the problem, or is there some setting I overlooked that will fix this? Please let me know if you need additional info to diagnose the problem.